# How can i map multiple ports in systemd-nspawn container?

Tags: network-namespaces, systemd-nspawn

I'm writing a container manager script which depends on nspawn, and the container is using a Virtual Ethernet Connection(-n opt).

but it looks like that nspawn only support port mapping for single port at this time

How can i map multiple ports from the guest machine to the host machine?

[nspawn doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html)

[my script](https://github.com/TeaHouseLab/ctcontainer/blob/main/codes/run/nspawn/nspawn_run.fish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-p support multiple times in one single command, so i use a loop to add ports one by one

Here's my code

```bash
set port_range $_flag_port
                if echo $port_range | grep -qs -
                    set -e port_mapping_tcp
                    set -e port_mapping_udp
                    set -e port_mapping
                    set port_counter 0
                    for port_arrary in (seq (echo $port_range | awk -F "-" '{print $1}') (echo $port_range | awk -F "-" '{print $2}'))
                        set port_counter (math $port_counter+1)
                        set port_mapping_tcp[$port_counter] "-ptcp:$port_arrary"
                        set port_mapping_udp[$port_counter] "-pudp:$port_arrary"
                    end
                else
                    if echo $port_range | grep -qs ,
                        set -e port_mapping_tcp
                        set -e port_mapping_udp
                        set -e port_mapping
                        set port_counter 0
                        for port_arrary in (echo $port_range | string split ,)
                            set port_counter (math $port_counter+1)
                            set port_mapping_tcp[$port_counter] "-ptcp:$port_arrary"
                            set port_mapping_udp[$port_counter] "-pudp:$port_arrary"
                        end
                    else
                        set port_mapping_tcp "-ptcp:$_flag_port"
                        set port_mapping_udp "-pudp:$_flag_port"
                    end
                end
                sudo systemd-nspawn --resolv-conf=off $port_mapping_tcp $port_mapping_udp -bnq -D $container
```